# expandable listview inside dialog gets error

Tags: android, dialog, expandablelistview

i want to perform an expandable listview inside dialog.But i get error in the line where i set the adapter `(l.setAdapter(expAdapter)` acording to logcat.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{ 

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getBaseContext());
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.menu);
        int id= getIntent().getExtras().getInt("id");   
     dbAdapter = new DBAdapter(this);
     dbAdapter=dbAdapter.open(); 

      int length = dbAdapter.getDetailsOf(proion_id).size();
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),  length, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


 loadData();
    ExpandableListView l = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.item_comments_explist);
    myExpandableAdapter expAdapter = new myExpandableAdapter(this,  dbAdapter.getDetailsOf(id), childs);
    l.setAdapter(expAdapter);  }
```

LogCat

> 07-02 06:24:37.317: E/AndroidRuntime(5460): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.techblogon.loginexample/com.techblogon.loginexample.ItemComments}: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   07-02 06:24:37.317: E/AndroidRuntime(5460):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
>   07-02 06:24:37.317: E/AndroidRuntime(5460):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
>   07-02 06:24:37.317: E/AndroidRuntime(5460):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
>   07-02 06:24:37.317: E/AndroidRuntime(5460):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
>   07-02 06:24:37.317: E/AndroidRuntime(5460):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>   07-02 06:24:37.317: E/AndroidRuntime(5460):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>   07-02 06:24:37.317: E/AndroidRuntime(5460):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
>   07-02 06:24:37.317: E/AndroidRuntime(5460):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   07-02 06:24:37.317: E/AndroidRuntime(5460):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>   07-02 06:24:37.317: E/AndroidRuntime(5460):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>   07-02 06:24:37.317: E/AndroidRuntime(5460):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
>   07-02 06:24:37.317: E/AndroidRuntime(5460):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   07-02 06:24:37.317: E/AndroidRuntime(5460): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   07-02 06:24:37.317: E/AndroidRuntime(5460):     at com.techblogon.loginexample.ItemComments.onCreate(ItemComments.java:65)
>   07-02 06:24:37.317: E/AndroidRuntime(5460):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
>   07-02 06:24:37.317: E/AndroidRuntime(5460):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>   07-02 06:24:37.317: E/AndroidRuntime(5460):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)

Comment: Post the log for the error you're getting

Answer (score 1):

After research i can't find any solutions.So i themed the activity as Dialog 
 ***android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"***